# Application insights and service fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348793/application-insights-in-service-fabric) from several months back on Application Insights and Service Fabric and I'm wondering if there is any new information.

I would really like to get CPU, Memory, Storage and other metrics out of service fabric and the reliable actors. Having it presented in a user friendly HUD like app insights provides would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you saw the new tab called "Matrics" in the SF explorer? It was added recently as part of SDK 2.2.

Comment: Also, if you right click the actor in solution explorer you can add App Insights to it.

Comment: Take a look at this project for full AI integration: https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the azure portal, you can now create a resource called 'Service Fabric Analytics' to create a nice dashboard for your cluster. Configure as cluster like described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/log-analytics-service-fabric/). It's OMS based, not Appinsights though.

> The Service Fabric Solution helps identify and troubleshoot issues
>   across your Service Fabric cluster, by providing visibility into how
>   your Service Fabric virtual machines are performing and how your
>   applications and micro-services are running. Available features
>   include:  • Get insight into your Service Fabric framework • Get
>   insight into the performance of your Service Fabric applications and
>   micro-services • View events from your applications and micro-services
>   Data collected: Service Fabric Reliable Service Events, Service Fabric
>   Actor Events, Service Fabric Operational Events, Event tracing for
>   Windows events and Windows event logs. Requirements: This solution
>   will only work if you have set up Azure Diagnostics on your Service
>   Fabric VMs, and have configured OMS to collect data for your WAD
>   tables.

Answer (score 0):

In service fabric with Eventflow https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow  you had a option to send the diagnostics data to multiple data stores like WAD Tables, OMS, elastic search and application insights. 
Have a look at it. It is really straight forward and easily integrate with ETW events and will serve your purpose.