# How to use requestBody from ServiceFabric.ServiceRemotingDispatcher.RequestResponseAsync

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, azure-service-fabric

Overriding the method `RequestResponseAsync` we are given the variable `byte[] requestBody`.
To deserialize this variable we use `DataContractSerializer` (or maybe `NetDataContractSerializer`) but either way we need to know what type it was before it was serialized.

```
    public override Task<byte[]> RequestResponseAsync(IServiceRemotingRequestContext requestContext, ServiceRemotingMessageHeaders messageHeaders, byte[] requestBody)
    {

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(requestBody)) {
            DataContractSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(object));
            object headers = dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
            // LOG headers here!
            // logger.log(headers.something);
        }

        return base.RequestResponseAsync(requestContext, messageHeaders, requestBody);
    }
```

What `Type` we replace `object` with to get `requestBody` to deserialize properly?  We want to deserialize it here specifically to log information from it and need to know the type `requestBody` was before the serialization in order to do that.

Comment: have you seen this related question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166193/how-to-add-message-header-to-the-request-when-using-default-client-of-azure-serv/34221661#34221661

Comment: @LoekD I updated the question, specifically we want to _deserialize_ `requestBody` and that other question didn't reveal anything about that part of it.

Comment: If you have control over who is calling you and the called service itself, you could add a header specifying the type @ the caller side and use that to deserialize @ server side.