# Service fabric communication by RPC with metadata

Tags: c#, azure, rpc, microservices, azure-service-fabric

In the `API Gateway` app I set to request traceId. Then over `HTTP` pass it to my stateless service. But service should call another service by `RPC` (using `IServiceRemotingListener`). How can I pass that traceId to other service?

I've done so far (according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting)):

```
public interface ICommunicationService : IService
{
    Task<string> FooAsync();
}

public class Stateless1 : StatelessService, ICommunicationService 
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners() 
    {
        return new[] { new ServiceInstanceListener(c => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(c)) };
    }       

    public Task<string> FooAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult("TraceId: " + TraceId);
    }
}
```

and trying to use it:

```
ICommunicationService service = ServiceProxy.Create<ICommunicationService>(new Uri("fabric:/App/Stateless1"));

string message = await service.FooAsync();
```

How can I pass that TraceId to other service b RPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use methods in SF remoting. Change the property into a method `GetCorrelationId` that returns it as `Task` of `int`. And add a method:

```
Task SetCorrelationId( int id){}
```

Or **preferably**, generate it on the caller and pass it as part of the message argument to 'FooAsync' which is better, because it keeps the service stateless.

Comment: Thanks. Are there other ways to pass CorrelationId by IServiceRemotingClient?

Comment: Yep, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166193/how-to-add-message-header-to-the-request-when-using-default-client-of-azure-serv/34221661#34221661    Using custom implementations of ```IServiceRemotingClient``` and ```ServiceRemotingDispatcher
```.

Comment: Thanks a lot for link and help